# WPF DataGrid with EF database first data binding issues

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to bind data from a table in an mssql db, i have followed the steps advised by MSDN. The problem is that my datagrid displays only headers and then repeats headers for the number of rows that my db has.
[image: Screenshot]

This is my code

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource testbazaEntitiesViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("testbazaEntitiesViewSource")));
        // Load data by setting the CollectionViewSource.Source property:
        // testbazaEntitiesViewSource.Source = [generic data source]
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource tabelaViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("tabelaViewSource")));
        // Load data by setting the CollectionViewSource.Source property:
        // tabelaViewSource.Source = [generic data source]
    }
}
}
```

This is the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="testbazaEntitiesViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:testbazaEntities}, CreateList=True}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="testbazaEntitiestabelaViewSource" Source="{Binding tabela, Source={StaticResource testbazaEntitiesViewSource}}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="tabelaViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:tabela}, CreateList=True}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource testbazaEntitiestabelaViewSource}">
    <DataGrid x:Name="tabelaDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource tabelaViewSource}}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dugovanjaColumn" Binding="{Binding dugovanja}" Header="dugovanja" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="iD_brojColumn" Binding="{Binding ID_broj}" Header="ID broj" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="imeColumn" Binding="{Binding ime}" Header="ime" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="oblik_nosaColumn" Binding="{Binding oblik_nosa}" Header="oblik nosa" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="plataColumn" Binding="{Binding plata}" Header="plata" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The database has 2 rows of data, i havent managed to display any of it, im very new to wpf, c# and coding in general, thanks for reading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create collection view source in code behind for wpf app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839448/how-to-create-collection-view-source-in-code-behind-for-wpf-app)

Comment: I have now realized that my model.tt file does not generate the ObservableCollection, even tho i modified the file as instructed, i really dont know what to do now

Comment: Where are you connecting to the `DBContext`? There is some code missing here. You have not shown where you query the database!

Comment: Also, why do you have two (or even three) `CollectionViewSource`s? One should be enough!

Comment: I have solved my issue, there was code missing as you said, thanks